# Carrierwave - crop image before upload?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, carrierwave

I am trying to implement image cropping into my rails app.  I watched this railscast https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ltoPZEzmtJA but it looks like the file is uploaded then it brings you to another page to crop.  Is it possible to crop the image before uploading it, or at least do it all at the same time?

Comment: Did you use CarrierWave? And do you have a  :process voor cropping?

Comment: @user4584963 Did you find solution to it?